How does C++23 happens before apply to std::memory_order_seq_cst?
Consider the following C++23 program:
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <thread>

#define LOAD_ORDER std::memory_order_seq_cst
#define STORE_ORDER std::memory_order_seq_cst

std::atomic_int v[2]{0, 0};
int r[2];

void
f(int i)
{
  v[i].store(1, STORE_ORDER);
  r[i] = v[1-i].load(LOAD_ORDER);
}

int
main()
{
  {
    std::jthread t0(f, 0);
    std::jthread t1(f, 1);
  }
  assert(r[0] || r[1]);
  return 0;
}

One thread stores 1 to  v[0] then loads v[1].  Concurrently, the other thread stores 1 to v[1] then loads v[0].  I want to ensure that at least one load returns 1.  My questions:

At a high level, sequentially consistent operations cannot be reordered, so this should work.  But how do you prove the above code is correct using only the sequenced before, synchronizes with, inter-thread happens before, and visible side effect concepts in the language spec?  For instance, it doesn't seem to be the case that one store happens before the other.

Would the code still be correct if I changed LOAD_ORDER to std::memory_order_relaxed and left STORE_ORDER as std::memory_order_seq_cst?  What about the converse of relaxing STORE_ORDER but not load?

What's the most relaxed or efficient value that I can set LOAD_ORDER and STORE_ORDER to and still guarantee the assertion will not fail?


Assume all the variables are on different cache lines--I just didn't add padding to make the example simpler.  Also assume no consume operations, so we can ignore the distinctions between weakly/strongly/plain happens before.

Re 1: See paragraph 4 here. There exists a single total order. The particular order can be any interleaving of the operations of the two threads and can be different each time. Prove that all possible orders give results consistent with your assert. Re 2: No, read note 5 on the same page

@Homer512 Paragraph 3 is talking about operations on the same memory location.  Do you you read paragraph 4 as no longer talking about a single memory location?  Like A and B could accessing different variables?  No, because paragraph goes on to talk about M as well, so I think it is only talking about A and B both accessing M.  But also a fence isn't to a single memory location, so I'm not sure.

Paragraph 4 is a bit confusing because it contains two clauses/constraints. The first talks about any pair of seq-cst. operations A and B where A strongly happens before B (those are the store and load within each thread in your case). The second talks about any A and B on the same object M that are coherence-ordered. Those are the load-store pairs across the two threads. The text is careful not to omit the object M when it is required.

So is the answer to my question that nothing weaker than seq_cst for both load and store would work, because a seq_cst load or store on a single object is weaker than a seq_cst fence.  But I could put a seq_cst fence betwen the load/store and make the load/store themselves relaxed and that would work?

For fences I just refer to this question. My brain is mush

I've been pondering the pure fence case some more and I think the standard got it wrong. A single full memory barrier between the store and load should be enough. It's a common demonstration case. But I don't see how this would be valid according to the standard.

Let's go through a couple of rules and scenarios.
t0-store is sequenced before t0-load, therefore t0-store strongly happens before t0-load; same with t1.
Without sequential consistency
In the absence of sequential consistency, we need to provide some inter-thread happens before relation between t0 and t1. Do any of the rules apply?

Does t0-store synchronize with t1-store or load? No. There is no relation with t1-store because they are independent atomic variables. It may synchronize with t1-load as a release-acquire pair but that is not guaranteed
Are there any dependency-orderings? No. The operations are all independent
Does t1-load synchronize with an evaluation X and X is sequenced before t0-store? There is no relevant operation before t0-store
Is t0-store sequenced before X and X inter-thread happens before t1-load? The only operation sequenced after t0-store is t0-load. That has no inter-thread relation with t1-load
Does t0-store inter-thread happen before X and X inter-thread happens before t1-load? That's just the transitive property. We only have two threads so it does not apply

Therefore the operations are potentially concurrent.. This is to be expected. Informally, an acquire load can be reordered before a release store and vice versa.
What we do know is that t0-store may be coherence-ordered before t1-load, and/or t1-store before t0-load.
With sequential consistency
Now let's introduce sequentially consistent operations into the mix. This gives us a single total order S with a set of rules. In particular this:

First, if A and B are memory_order​::​seq_cst operations and A strongly happens before B, then A precedes B in S.

We have established that t0-store strongly happens before t0-load. So t0-store precedes t0-load in S. Same with t1. Therefore, in the single total order, the loads always come after the store by their own thread. You cannot have a load in the single total order before at least one store. So at least one store will always be visible to a load.
The only other rule regarding sequentially consistent operations (not fences) is this:

Second, for every pair of atomic operations A and B on an object M, where A is coherence-ordered before B, the following four conditions are required to be satisfied by S:

if A and B are both memory_order​::​seq_cst operations, then A precedes B in S


All that means for us is that if a load sees the value of a store, it is ordered after it in the single total order. Not much surprise there.
At this point it is important to note that the rules only apply to sequentially consistent operations. There are no rules that apply between sequentially consistent and other atomic operations. With regard to any other operations, sequentially consistent operations simply act as release stores or acquire loads. The standard is very explicit in warning against this style of mixing.

Note 5: memory_order​::​seq_cst ensures sequential consistency only for a program that is free of data races and uses exclusively memory_order​::​seq_cst atomic operations. Any use of weaker ordering will invalidate this guarantee unless extreme care is used. In many cases, memory_order​::​seq_cst atomic operations are reorderable with respect to other atomic operations performed by the same thread.


All atomic operations with sequential consistency happen in a global total order.
So you have stores to v[0] and to v[1], lets call them S0 and S1 and similarly loads L0 and L1.
This order is required to be consistent with the sequenced-with relation. In the first thread you have that S0 is sequenced-before L1 and in the second that S1 is sequenced-before L0, i.e. S0 < L1 and S1 < L0.
In the global total order you have either L0 < L1 or L1 < L0.
L0 < L1 together with S1 < L0 implies S1 < L1, i.e. L1 will load 1. For L1 < L0 you similarly get that L0 will load 1.
Either way, the assert is satisfied.

If you weaken the memory ordering, then the assert will not be guaranteed anymore.

I think you mean "...in the second that S1 is sequenced-before L0" rather than L2.

@user3188445 fixed

This is useful and I upvoted you, but I'm going to hold out for a more language-lawyer type answer that justifies this in terms of normative language.  In particular, I'm having trouble understanding why making the loads relaxed and the stores seq_cst would not also work, given that a seq_cst store should act like a fence as well.

@user3188445 Single total order is only guaranteed for seq-cst operations. The text is pretty clear on that. For anything else, a seq-cst store simply acts like a release operation. A relaxed (or acquire) load can be reordered before a release store. You may not see this happen IRL because compilers don't reorder atomics even if the standard allows it and because the CPU probably needs a full memory fence for the store, but according to the standard, that's still possible.

Yes but if the stores are seq_cst and hence ordered by happens before, and the loads are relaxed, the loads will still be sequenced after the stores, so why wouldn't that ensure at least one load happens after one of the stores?  I would love to understand this in terms of normative language...

@user3188445 Sequential consistency ordering is explicitly not required to be consistent with the happens-before relation. But regardless, the total order applies only to operations with sequential consistency and you haven't established any happens-before relation between any operations, especially not the two stores, inter-thread yet. You would need at least acquire/release to establish that.

@user3188445: It's rather difficult to prove a negative like that.  The C++ rule is essentially "everything is allowed unless explicitly forbidden".  So in some sense, if you think that the assert cannot fail, the burden of proof falls on you to prove it.  If you can't prove it doesn't happen, you must assume that it can.

@user3188445: Otherwise, the argument in terms of "normative language" would look kind of like the following: someone proposes a possible execution for the program, stating what values are returned by all the loads, and says what they think is the modification order of each variable, what is the happens-before order, what is the sequentially consistent total order, etc.  Then you go through every relevant part of the standard and verify that this proposal is consistent with every single rule.
